# How to make this site multi-lingual?

Tags: support

Tor has a lot of non-english-speaker users around the world. How can we make this SE site useful for them? Is there a way to make an SE site multilingual?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Stack Exchange does not run non-English or multi-lingual sites except the sites which are about languages like for example [German Language & Usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/). On those sites it is allowed to ask and answer questions in both English and the language the site is about. For a long time there are several non-English sites waiting in the pre-beta phase to get a localized interface: [Stack Overflow in various languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=stack%20overflow). None of them has started yet. :-(

In fact Jeff Atwood - one of Stack Exchange co-founders wrote:

> It is not, nor has it ever been, our goal to be the one place in the world for all programming information in every possible human language.

The complete blog article from 2009: [Non-English Question Policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

Since that time a lot has changed and individual sites are mostly managed by their communities. I am not sure how much may Stack Exchange Inc. interfere with decisions made on individual sites but I can imagine that a community can decide to use multiple languages. Probably administrators and more experienced users which are in contact with Stack Exchange Inc. can tell more about what is possible.

Comment: I wonder if we could require the use of tags for questions in languages other than English?